# Joint density of order statistics (general case)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Let $X:=(X_1,...,X_n)$ be a random vector (we can assume that the $X_i$'s are exchangeable) with joint density $(x_1,...,x_n)\mapsto f_X(x_1,...,x_n)$.

No independence assumption is made. Then, what can we tell about the joint law of the order statistics $(X_{(1)},...,X_{(n)})$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "joint law of order statistics"?

Comment: @becko I mean the law of the random vectroe $(X_{(1)},...,X_{(n)})$

Comment: What kind of information are you looking for?

Comment: @MarcusM actually i found it. I was looking for an expression of the density probability function of the random order statistics vector in a more general case than iid. If the rv are exchangeable then the formula is the same as in the independent case.